# Did Nietzsche have anything to say about the trans-Atlantic slavery trade?

Tags: political-philosophy, nietzsche

Given that there are over 300 references to slavery in Nietzsches work did he, in any of his works, address what was the most significant revival of slavery since Graeco-Roman times, that is the trans-Atlantic slavery trade?

If so, how does he square it with his theory of the *ubermenschen* (superman) and *untermenschen* (subhuman) and with slavery being an essential part of aristocratic society, neccessary for aristocrats to secure and preserve their privileges of being aristocrats?

Further, one Nietzschean scholar pointed out that though Nietzsche attracts a great deal of commentary there is very little scrutiny of his political philosophy in regards to slavery. Is this merely because Nietzschean scholarship is - I'm supposing - mostly from a white European background, or are there deeper reasons?

Comment: He linked the "salvation and future of the human race with the unconditional dominance" of master morality and called master morality "a higher order of values, the noble ones, those that say Yes to life, those that guarantee the future." Just as "there is an order of rank between man and man," there is also an order of rank "between morality and morality." Indeed, Nietzsche waged a philosophic war against the slave morality of Christianity in his "revaluation of all values" in order to bring about the victory of a new master morality that he called the "philosophy of the future". *Wikipedia*

Comment: Nietzsche's idea of slave is different than the actual "a human that is a property of another human". It is that one is just a weakling. One can't do what he wishes and blames others for his own weakness.

Comment: @Bread: It seems the human race was doing very well without N coming along and telling us we’ve got it wrong. He’s basically an aristocrat who wants to roll back all the political freedoms gained since the French Revolution, and even earlier. As far as I see it he’s swimming against the tide of time.

Comment: @rus9384: That’s not a notion new to N he’s appropriated it from ancient ethics about slavish nature’s which justified their system of slavery. Does this mean that N was being slavish in being a ‘weakling’ when he collapsed mentally in the last decade of his life?

Comment: Did he have a choice not to collapse? Probably, not. Slaves always have a choice and never use an opportunity.

Comment: @rus9384: And ‘weaklings’, do they have a ‘choice’ in being weak? I can’t say I think much of that defence. Most people have strengths and weaknesses, and this varies during their lifetime; dividing the entire human race into a tiny elite of the strong and a large mass of weak strikes me as something of a joke.

Comment: That is something Nietzsche liked to do. But still I do not appreciate those who whine that others took something from instead of asking for help and uniting. Would be a great progress.

Comment: @rus9384: To do what - to make jokes? To me he’s the big anti-joke! Asking for justice for other people, that is reparations, restitution’s and so on is not whining, it’s part of justice. Of course, justice was something that N was not at all concerned with.

Comment: @Mozibur Ullah I agree with you. It's disturbing that anyone would take him very seriously. My interest in him is purely from the psychological / sociological viewpoint. Meaning that I'm trying to understand how he became that way, and how and why he influences certain people so much. I will confess that I try in my own inept way to be a little subversive against the brand of philosophy that has been established in his name.

Comment: It's not. But I often hear how people say that society does not treat them in the way they deserve. That those who appeared to be better than them, say, great scientists or artists, are actually bastards and actually must give them their resources. That is an awful position.

Comment: @rus9384: To me Nietzsche is the world’s greatest whiner. Whining about a billion Christians! That’s a lot of complaining. And not just Christianity, also *all* the main religions as there compassion is a central value - a value at which N sneers at. So he’s possibly complaining about roughly three billion people. Have you read Dostoyevskys *Underground Man*? He has exactly that whinging and whining tone. When people are talk about redistributative justice they’re not talking about the great artists or scientists but generally about the tremendous power that corporations now have over our ...

Comment: ... lives. This is what the 99.99% were angry about.

Comment: But Nietzsche never said he is somehow a master or like that. Anyway, I don't see the purpose of question. As I said (rephrasing), slave is the one who, being stuck in the pit, won't climb stairs that someone else brought them to help, but would continue to sit in the pit and whine that they are in the pit.

Comment: @rus9384: Aren’t you just engaging in Nietzschian apologetics? He would have liked to have been Napoleon but unluckily for him and luckily for the rest of us - he wasn’t. I think you are mistaken: masters can make slaves out of other people, and historically they have. Try telling the the millions of African slaves brought over to the USA leaving devastated communities and nations behind to see their slavery as an opportunity to climb from the bottom of society by ‘some stairs’. I don’t think you will get very far.

Comment: Why do you think that I call actual slavery that type of stairs? Even a master can be caught, but probably he will try to escape.

Comment: @rus9384: I’m not much interested about what you think about home decor and furnishings. If you have anything of significance to relate about the substance of the question then please do so.